# Data from controller is not fetching into Jquery Datatable in MVC(Without using Entity framework)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, stored-procedures, datatables

Find the below code and help me where i went wrong as data is not fetching into jQuery Datatable(Data is displaying only in JSON formate)

Step:1 Created the Datatbase acccess layer, then a class named as Db2

```
        public class Db2
        {
           SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["con"].ConnectionString);
            public DataSet show_data()
            {
              SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("SP_Company_All", con);
              com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
              SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(com);
              DataSet ds = new DataSet();
              da.Fill(ds);
               return ds;
            }
        }
```

Step:2 Creating the empty controller and coded as per the below

```
     public class Company1Controller : Controller
        {
            Database_Access_layer.Db2 db2layer = new Database_Access_layer.Db2();

            // GET: Company1
            public ActionResult Index()
            {
                return View();
            }
            public JsonResult get_data()
            {
                DataSet ds = db2layer.show_data();
                List<Company1> listcomp = new List<Company1>();
                foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
                {
                    listcomp.Add(new Company1
                    {
                        CompanyID = Convert.ToInt32(dr["CompanyID"]),
                        CompanyName = dr["CompanyName"].ToString(),
                        CompanyCode = dr["CompanyCode"].ToString(),
                        Wecare_companyId = Convert.ToInt32(dr["Wecare_companyId"]),
                        LicenseCount = Convert.ToInt32(dr["LicenseCount"]),
                        active = Convert.ToBoolean(dr["active"]),
                        ModifiedBy = Convert.ToInt32(dr["ModifiedBy"]),
                        Lastmodifiedon = Convert.ToDateTime(dr["Lastmodifiedon"])
                    });
                }
                var data = listcomp;
                return Json(listcomp, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }
```

Step3:Then The View Part be like..........

```
            @{
        ViewBag.Title = "Company1 Page";
        Layout = null;
    }

    <html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
        <title>Index</title> 

            <!-- CDN LINKS-->
            <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootswatch/4.3.1/cerulean/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
            <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
            <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
            <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
        </head>
    <body>
        <div class="jumbotron">
            <h1>DataTable Example</h1>
            <p class="lead">A project dedicated to data table example in MVC</p>
        </div>
        <br />
        <center>
            <div style="width: auto; border: 1px solid black; padding: 3px" ;>
                <table id="dataTable">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>CompanyID</th>
                            <th>CompanyName</th>
                            <th>CompanyCode</th>
                            <th>WeCareCompanyID</th>
                            <th>LicenseCount</th>
                            <th>Active</th>
                            <th>ModifiedBy</th>
                            <th>LastModifiedOn</th>                        
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                </table>
            </div>
        </center>
----- Scripting Part be like
        <script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function () {
                    $.ajax({
                        "url": "@Url.Action("get_data", "Company1")",
                        "method": "post",
                        "dataType" : "json",
                        success: function (data) {
                            $('#dataTable').DataTable({
                                paging: true,
                                sort: true,
                                searching: true,
                                scrollY: 200,
                                data:data,
                                columns: [
                                    { 'data': 'CompanyID'},
                                    { 'data': 'CompanyName' },
                                    { 'data': 'CompanyCode' },
                                    { 'data': 'Wecare_companyId' },
                                    { 'data': 'LicenseCount' },
                                    { 'data': 'active' },
                                    { 'data': 'ModifiedBy' },
                                    { 'data': 'Lastmodifiedon'}                               
                                ]
                            });
                        }
                    });
                });
        </script>
    </body>
    </html>
    }

Here is a code of database access layer, controller and view too but data is not displaying in Datatable. Tried in Multiple ways.But No Luck
```

Comment: what's error message on line 24 ?

Comment: Column 'LicenseCount' does not belong to table Table.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: Column 'LicenseCount' does not belong to table Table.

Comment: Delete the line `LicenseCount = Convert.ToInt32(dr["LicenseCount"]),` to avoid the exception. It is clearly telling you that `LicenseCount` is not a column in the table returned by your stored procedure. You can alternatively, add the column to your stored procedure. If you need help with that, post the code for `SP_Company_All`.

Comment: This error Occurred just because of SP which am using as if now the error went off after changing the SP.Now The data is displaying in Json Format not fetching into the data table...!

Comment: @kiranr In your `Controller`, add this: `List<Company1> data=listcomp.ToList();` and then send this List to your JSON: `return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);`

Comment: @RahulSharma Tried but Still its returning the Json data itself.

Comment: @kiranr Yes, your `data` list should be returned as JSON to your View, where it will be picked up by the plugin. What behavior are you expecting here?

Comment: @RahulSharma I just want to display the output in the jQuery Datatable which can be sortable, paging must be enabled and auto search functionality must be there...! In future I want to use the same Datatable to perform the CRUD operation too...

Comment: @kiranr In your code, you have specified your `id="dataTable"` but when you call it is: `$('#datatable').dataTable`. It should be: `$('#dataTable').dataTable`

Comment: To get rid of this confusion I already tried by renaming the table I'd as Mytable and when I call I called the same as:$('Mytable').dataTable. but it's also returning the JSON output itself ☹️

Comment: Dear Rahul thank you for your time and support but I dint get a time to touch my laptop from past 12 hour I will update you within next 48 hrs as am busy with some other things

Comment: @RahulSharma: Sad to say that still output data is in JSON format not in the Datatable :-(

Comment: @kiranr I am making a sample application for you using data tables. I will let you know when done

Comment: @Rahul thankyou for your kindness am waiting for your update 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I have setup a sample working repository regarding your problem [here](https://github.com/rahsharm77/DataTableExample). You can clone this repository and play around with it. I have hardcoded your `List<Company1> listcomp = new List<Company1>();` with predefined values but it is assumed that your data from the database would be similar to my hardcoded values.

I am showing you the associated `Model`, `View` and `Contoller` code and a sample output of the application.

Please note that I am using the CDN links for your `js` and `css` files:

Your `Model` will look like:

```
using System;

namespace DataTablesExample
{
    public class Company1
    {
        public int CompanyID { get; set; }
        public string CompanyName { get; set; }
        public string CompanyCode { get; set; }
        public int Wecare_companyId { get; set; }
        public int LicenseCount { get; set; }
        public bool active { get; set; }
        public int ModifiedBy { get; set; }
        public DateTime Lastmodifiedon { get; set; }
        //Adding a string datetime since it is easier to manipulate in backend
        public string Lastmodifiedonstring { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Your `Controller` will look like:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace DataTablesExample.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }


        public JsonResult get_date()
        {
            List<Company1> listcomp = new List<Company1>();

            //This is how you are setting your company list. I will show you a basic example by adding hardcoded values
            //DataSet ds = db2layer.show_data();

            //foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
            //{
            //    listcomp.Add(new Company1
            //    {
            //        CompanyID = Convert.ToInt32(dr["CompanyID"]),
            //        CompanyName = dr["CompanyName"].ToString(),
            //        CompanyCode = dr["CompanyCode"].ToString(),
            //        Wecare_companyId = Convert.ToInt32(dr["Wecare_companyId"]),
            //        LicenseCount = Convert.ToInt32(dr["LicenseCount"]),
            //        active = Convert.ToBoolean(dr["active"]),
            //        ModifiedBy = Convert.ToInt32(dr["ModifiedBy"]),
            //        Lastmodifiedon = Convert.ToDateTime(dr["Lastmodifiedon"])
            //    });
            //}

            listcomp.Add(new Company1
            {
                CompanyID = 1,
                CompanyName = "Company 1",
                CompanyCode = "C1",
                Wecare_companyId = 1,
                LicenseCount = 1,
                active = true,
                ModifiedBy = 1,
                Lastmodifiedon = DateTime.Now,
                Lastmodifiedonstring = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/M/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
            });

            listcomp.Add(new Company1
            {
                CompanyID = 2,
                CompanyName = "Company 2",
                CompanyCode = "C2",
                Wecare_companyId = 2,
                LicenseCount = 2,
                active = true,
                ModifiedBy = 1,
                Lastmodifiedon = DateTime.Now,
                Lastmodifiedonstring = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/M/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
            });

            listcomp.Add(new Company1
            {
                CompanyID = 3,
                CompanyName = "Company 3",
                CompanyCode = "C3",
                Wecare_companyId = 1,
                LicenseCount = 3,
                active = true,
                ModifiedBy = 1,
                Lastmodifiedon = DateTime.Now,
                Lastmodifiedonstring= DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/M/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
            });
            var data = listcomp;
            return Json(listcomp, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
}
```

And finally your `View` will look like:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
    Layout = null;
}

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>
    @*<link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
    <link href="~/Content/bootstrap4.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="~/Scripts/DataTables/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/DataTables/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>*@

    <!-- CDN LINKS-->
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootswatch/4.3.1/cerulean/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1>DataTable Example</h1>
        <p class="lead">A project dedicated to data table example in MVC</p>
    </div>
    <br />
    <center>
        <div style="width: auto; border: 1px solid black; padding: 3px" ;>
            <table id="dataTable">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Company ID</th>
                        <th>Company Name</th>
                        <th>Company Code</th>
                        <th>WeCare Company ID</th>
                        <th>License Count</th>
                        <th>Active</th>
                        <th>Modified By</th>
                        <th>Last Modified On</th>
                        <th>Last Modified On Server String</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
            </table>
        </div>
    </center>
    <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    "url": "@Url.Action("get_date", "Home")",
                    "method": "post",
                    "dataType" : "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        $('#dataTable').DataTable({
                            paging: true,
                            sort: true,
                            searching: true,
                            scrollY: 200,
                            data:data,
                            columns: [
                                { 'data': 'CompanyID'},
                                { 'data': 'CompanyName' },
                                { 'data': 'CompanyCode' },
                                { 'data': 'Wecare_companyId' },
                                { 'data': 'LicenseCount' },
                                { 'data': 'active' },
                                { 'data': 'ModifiedBy' },
                                {
                                    'data': 'Lastmodifiedon'
                                    //'render': function (jsonDate) {
                                    //    var date = new Date(parseInt(jsonDate.substr(13)));
                                    //    var month = date.getMonth() + 1;
                                    //    return month + "/" + date.getDate() + "/" + date.getFullYear();
                                    //}
                                },
                                { 'data': 'Lastmodifiedonstring' }
                            ]
                        });
                    }
                });
            });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Sample output from the application:

[image]

If you will notice the last two fields in the output, you will see that one field is the unformatted `DateTime` field sent from the model, and the other field is a formatted `DateTime` field to `Date` string. This is beacause DataTables require a `Date` field to display values. So you have two options here:

1. You can either convert your `DateTime` field in your `Controller` method to a formatted `Date` string and send it your `View`. That is what I am doing and the last field of the output (Last Modified on Server String). I would prefer this method because C# provides efficient methods to format your `DateTime` to a `Date` in the format you require.
2. The other option is to send your `DateTime` value to your `DataTable` and format it there as per your need. I have not tried out that method but I feel it can cause potential problems in rendering your value.

I hope this helps you out.

Cheers!

Comment: Dear Rahul thank you for your time and response... Actually am trying to fetch a data from one of the table from my database. but I can clearly see that you are taken a data in controller itself.. As am getting the JSON data I hope am clear about controller part in my project but I wanted to know where I went wrong in view part in my project I tried a lot of ways but it's still not working it's returning JSON data itself

Comment: @kiranr Did you try out my method? You just need to set the database values to your model. I am hardcoding them but you can simply get it from database. It shouldnt matter. Just follow the steps in my answer.

Comment: Dear Rahul I tried but again a bad luck..! Data is not fetching to Datatable only html table headers are displaying.

Comment: @kiranr Can you update your question with your latest attempt for this problem.

Comment: Updated the view and controller part

Comment: Thanks a Ton for your end to end support..it's working fine.